# Add custom page to admin menu visible only to admins

Tags: wordpress, admin, backend

I want to build a custom survey and display his results in the wordpress backend.

I added a new admin menu item like this:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_survey' );

function register_survey(){
    add_menu_page( 'Survey', 'Survey', 'manage_options', '/survey/survey-admin.php', '', '/wp-admin/survey/icon.png', 30 );
}
```

The menu item named Survey appears in the backend. When i click it goes to /wp-admin/survey/survey-admin.php displaying my php file contents, but the dashboard dissapears with the sidebar menus... This page is also visible to everyone and wordpress function is_admin doesn't work anymore in this page...

What's the correct solution? I just want to display my custom page on wordpress backend and be able to check if the user is admin or not. Do i need to create a plugin for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by creating a plugin and add this code:

```
<?php

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_survey' );

function register_survey() {

    //create new top-level menu
    add_menu_page('Survey', 'Survey', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'survey_page',plugins_url('/icon.png', __FILE__));
}


function survey_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
<h2>Survey</h2>

MY TEXT HERE


<?php if ( is_admin() ) {
  echo '<p>is admin!</p>';
}
?>

</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to check the users capabilities using `current_user_can()`

```
if ( current_user_can('edit_files') ) {
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_survey' );
}
```

Here is a list of capabilities for each type of user: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Administrator

Comment: The menu item ”Survey” appears correctly only for admins, but when i click it it goes to my simple page survey-admin.php and i donțt have the wordpress dashboard anymore. That wouldn't be a big issue if you could use is_admin function on my simple page, but no wordpress function is available anymore... is there a way to attach a print-screen here?

Comment: You should really take a look at the `is_admin()` function, it's only to be used if the current page is in the administrator panel, not to determine if the current user is an admin. I am curious how no WordPress function is available yet you are using functions like `add_menu_page()` and `add_action()`. Just upload the screenshot to a website a post the link.